# ORA-04091: table name is mutating - when trigger from child table wants to update parent table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have 2 simple tables:

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS
( ORDER_KEY number(10) NOT NULL,
  ORDER_NR varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  LAST_UPDATE DATE,
  CONSTRAINT ORDERS_PK PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_KEY)
);

CREATE TABLE ORDER_POSITIONS
( ORDER_POS_KEY number(10) NOT NULL,
  ORDER_POS_NR number(10),
  ORDER_POS_DESCRIPTION varchar2(50),
  ORDER_KEY NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT ORDER_POSITIONS_PK PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_POS_KEY),
  CONSTRAINT ORDERS_FK
    FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_KEY)
    REFERENCES ORDERS(ORDER_KEY)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

On the table ORDER_POSITIONS I created a trigger which should update the column LAST_UPDATE whenever a position is deleted.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TGAUDIT_ORDER_POS
AFTER DELETE
    ON ORDER_POSITIONS 
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

BEGIN
    UPDATE ORDERS O SET O.LAST_UPDATE = SYSDATE WHERE O.ORDER_KEY = :OLD.ORDER_KEY;   
END;
```

If I delete a position from the table ORDER_POSITION, everything is working fine (the column LAST_UPDATE is updated).

However, if I want to delete an order, all its positions are gonna be deleted, too (via CASCADE DELETE). At this moment also the trigger on the table ORDER_POSITIONS is being raised and it wants to update the column of the table which is currently being deleted - ORDERS. Obviously I get here the error : ORA-04091 Table ORDERS is mutating.

Is there a way to get it solved?

Comment: Does adding a DEFERRABLE clause to the foreign key help?

Comment: No, I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it finally using a compound trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TGAUDIT_ORDER_POS
  FOR DELETE ON ORDER_POSITIONS
    COMPOUND TRIGGER
     
    TYPE parent_key_type IS TABLE OF ORDERS.ORDER_KEY%TYPE;
    parent_keys parent_key_type := parent_key_type();
    
    AFTER EACH ROW IS BEGIN
      IF DELETING THEN 
        BEGIN 
          parent_keys.extend;
          parent_keys(parent_keys.last) := :old.ORDER_KEY;
        END;
      END IF;
    END AFTER EACH ROW;
    
    AFTER STATEMENT IS BEGIN
      FOR i IN 1..parent_keys.count LOOP
        UPDATE DEVART_TEST.ORDERS O SET O.LAST_UPDATE = SYSDATE WHERE O.ORDER_KEY = parent_keys(i);   
      END LOOP;
    END AFTER STATEMENT;
    
END;
```

**UPDATE**: Another option would be to catch this specific exception within the regular trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TGAUDIT_ORDER_POS
AFTER DELETE
  ON ORDER_POSITIONS 
  FOR EACH ROW

  DECLARE
    TABLE_MUTATING EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(TABLE_MUTATING, -4091 );

BEGIN
    UPDATE ORDERS O SET O.LAST_UPDATE = SYSDATE WHERE O.ORDER_KEY = :OLD.ORDER_KEY;   
    EXCEPTION 
      WHEN TABLE_MUTATING THEN 
        NULL; -- suppress 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recreate the foreign-key constraint without the `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause and delete all order positions before deleting an order.  That way you avoid the mutating table error by not having two tables mutating at the same time.

Comment: Although this would be a solution, it is not that easy to apply it our case. Reason: We would like to add this kind of auditing for several tables. Removing CASCADE DELETE constraint would mean, that we have to find and change all places in our large and old codebase where those tables are being deleted and extend these methods with manual deletion of their children.